# Way to retrieve all the files from Special Folder C#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, file-io, xamarin.ios

I have been trying to retrieve all the files from the Special Folder. 
I am saving it in this form:

```
var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            var filename = Path.Combine(documents, InputName.Text);
            File.WriteAllText(filename, string);
```

Where inputName.Text is the user input name. Lets say I am using my name as filename.

I have been trying to retrieve it through:

```
var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string[] temp1 =Directory.GetFiles(documents);
```

But it is returning an empty array. 
Is there a way to retrieve all the files from it?

Comment: What does the call to `Environment.GetFolderPath` return?  Is there anything in that folder?

Comment: Yes, I have added few files with different names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any issue in your below code. In fact, I tried below in my sample console application and it returns array correctly. are you sure that you have required permission on the special folder?

```
    var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    string[] temp1 =Directory.GetFiles(documents);
```

Comment: Yes, I am actually trying to display all the files on the TableView. It returns empty table. I do have all the required permissions because I am also able to send it to the server and get back the output. Is there any permission required to display the file names?

Comment: if you put temp1.Length , what you get?

Comment: It is working. I had an error at some other place because of what the table was not being populated. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Is there a way to get the filename. If I use Path.GetFileName(documents) it returns "Documents" but I want "Documents/Prashant". Any suggestions?

Comment: foreach(string fileName in temp1)
                Console.WriteLine(fileName + "");